# Why isn't the tensor series an algebra, while the tensor algebra is?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products, formal-power-series

I am looking to understand why the free tensor series, denoted $T((V))$, is not an algebra, while the free tensor algebra, denoted $T(V)$, is.

To clarify definitions:

- Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$.
- The tensor algebra $T(V)$ is the direct sum of tensor powers of $V$, i.e., $T(V) = \bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty} T^n(V)$, where $T^n(V) = V^{\otimes n}$.
- The tensor series $T((V))$ is the set of all sequences $(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ where $a_i \in T^i(V)$.

I understand that $T(V)$ is an algebra because it is closed under the operations of vector addition and tensor multiplication, both of which are well-defined.

The main problem I see for $T((V))$ is that multiplication might not be well-defined. Let $A = (a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$ and $B = (b_0, b_1, b_2, \ldots)$ be two elements of $T((V))$. When we try to define the product $AB = (c_0, c_1, c_2, \ldots)$, the coefficient $c_n$ is the sum over all $i$ from $0$ to $n$ of $a_i \otimes b_{n-i}$.

To further simplify the question, consider the case where $V$ is a one-dimensional vector space over $F$. In this case, the tensor algebra $T(V)$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $F[x]$, and the tensor series $T((V))$ is isomorphic to the ring of formal power series $F[[x]]$. If I understand correctly, $F[[x]]$ is an algebra.

Why is it that $T((V))$ fails to be an algebra in general, whereas $F[[x]]$ is an algebra? I would appreciate any insights or references that could help shed light on this question.

Comment: It is an algebra. We call it the algebra of formal power series in non-commuting variables, or the completed tensor algebra, or probably many other names.

Comment: Why do you think it is not an algebra, by the way?

Comment: Well, the literature I have been reading (rough path theory) and in conferences I have heard people talk about the free tensor algebra, vs the free tensor series, some of them claimed the latter was not an algebra. So no reason in particular

Comment: The only issue I see (even with the product of two formal power series in a single variable) is that a product of two convergent series for some r>0 might be non convergent for all r>0, but this has nothing to do with the algebraic structure.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, the product of two elements $a,b\in T((V))$ is well-defined as $(c_n)_{n\ge 0}$ with $c_n= \sum_{i=0}^n a^i \otimes b^{n-i}$, and this can be show to be distributive over sums and compatible with scalars, which proves it is an algebra

Comment: The algebra structure has nothing to do with convergence, just like $F[[x]]$. If you have a reasonably well-behaved sense of convergence then the convergent series may form a subalgebra.

Comment: Why do you think the multiplication may not be well-defined? You seem to have defined it without making any choices.

Comment: In my experience, the place where people say "but this isn't really an algebra" is the following: you have some infinite-dimensional algebra (maybe, some fancy ring of power series) and you have some elements you like in it (maybe countably many of them) and so you take their span, and then you find yourself in the situation where a product of members of your subspace doesn't lie in the subspace because it is an *infinite* linear combination of your chosen generators.  If it would help, I can provide particular references where this comes up.

Comment: That's more or less like picking a mojito and saying "but this isn't really an algebra". Actually less, because with the mojito you can at least drown your disappointment with the mojito.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Well perhaps; often in this context you're in a situation where you'd expect or hope your subspace to again be an algebra.  See Section 1.5 here for a concrete example: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2209.03551.pdf